# My function runs only once

Tags: javascript, html, css

> I want  my button to make text in textarea cut to the clipboard and
>   the button rotates simultaneously each time I click it. I got it to
>   work, however it only rotates once, next time I click it, it'll cut
>   the text but button will not rotate.

**HTML**
my button and textarea

```
<div class="box-2-wrap">

<textarea class="out-put"></textarea>

<button type="button" id="copyEmailsButton" onclick="copyEmails()">Copy Emails</button>

</div>
```

**CSS**
my stylesheet

```
.box-2-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border: 0px solid #333;
}
.box-2-wrap textarea {
    flex:1;
    padding: 4%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: #333;
    color: gold;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    font-size: 110%;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.box-2-wrap button {
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 10px 2%;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 6% auto;
    background-color: #178E44;
    color: white;
    font-size: 120%;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}
```

**JS**
my JavaScript

```
function unSelectAll(){
        var output = document.getElementsByClassName("out-put")[0];
            output.innerHTML = "";
    }
}

function copyEmails(){
    var output = document.getElementsByClassName("out-put")[0];
        output.select();
        document.execCommand('copy');
        unSelectAll();
    var copyEmailsButton = document.getElementById("copyEmailsButton");

    if (copyEmailsButton.style.animation !== "rotate 1s") {
        copyEmailsButton.style.animation = "rotate 1s";
    }else{
        copyEmailsButton.style.animation = "none";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the if-else block in copyEmails you specify, that the button will rotate for one second, if the animation-style isn't set "to rotate 1s". But if it is, it will just set the animation-style to none.

If you click on the button a third time, you will notife, that it will rotate again. This is because with the 2nd click, you have set the animation Style to none again.

This means, your Button will switch and rotate every 2nd click!

To let the button rotate everytime you click, change the if-else block to:

```
copyEmailsButton.style.animation = "rotate 1s";
setTimeout(function() {
copyEmailsButton.style.animation = "none" 
}, 1000);
```

This sets the animation style to none again after the animation is finished, every time you click the button.

Answer (score 0):

1 there is an error in your `unselctAll` function, one extra close `}` should be removed

2 reset the button style before next click, as in this example below

```js
function unSelectAll(){
        var output = document.getElementsByClassName("out-put")[0];
            output.innerHTML = "";
    
}

function copyEmails(){
    var output = document.getElementsByClassName("out-put")[0];
        output.select();
        document.execCommand('copy');
        unSelectAll();
    var copyEmailsButton = document.getElementById("copyEmailsButton");

    if (copyEmailsButton.style.animation !== "rotate 1s") {
        copyEmailsButton.style.animation = "rotate 1s";
    }else{
        copyEmailsButton.style.animation = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
.box-2-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border: 0px solid #333;
}
.box-2-wrap textarea {
    flex:1;
    padding: 4%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: #333;
    color: gold;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    font-size: 110%;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.box-2-wrap button {
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 10px 2%;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 6% auto;
    background-color: #178E44;
    color: white;
    font-size: 120%;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<textarea class="out-put" onmouseover="copyEmailsButton.style.animation = 'none';" placeholder="always click here before clicking the button"></textarea>

<button type="button" id="copyEmailsButton" onclick="copyEmails()">Copy Emails</button>

</div>
```